# iptables and multiple nat redirections

Tags: iptables, virtual-machine, vps

I have about 20 VPS (running on a local IP) on my machine and I am redirecting certain ports using iptables on those VPS's like this with a script:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d %hostIP% --dport %real_port% -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination %vps_local_ip%":%vps_destination_port%
```

In order to refresh (new vps created or deleted) I have to run like 2000 iptables commands, first I delete all rules and then I insert them again, sometimes a few commands are skipped because iptables could not process it that fast, adding an interval is not an option as I need to complete these commands fast.

Is there any better solution for this problem ?

Comment: "sometimes a few commands are skipped because iptables could not process it that fast" What makes you think that? `iptables` returns after the kernel has executed the change (or tried to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a reason to reset all the rules when one VPS has changed. Unless you meant 2000 commands per VPS but in that case I would assume you are doing something wrong.

In general I suggest that you have two chains for each VPS, an active and an inactive one. If you should really need wo wait between two `iptables` commands then just do it – while configuring the inactive chain. When this is done then you change the reference from the active to the inactive chain in the main chain (probably `PREROUTING`).

If you are using many `iptables` commands for checking which VPS is the target then you may start using `ipset` in order to get this done with a single command.

**example**

You create two chains for all the active and all the inactive chains. This allows a change without race condition.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j chaingroup_a

iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_a -j vps_1a
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_a -j vps_2a
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_a -j vps_3a
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_a -j ACCEPT # stop applying rules

iptables -t nat -A vps_1a -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 42 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:4242
```

If the configuration is to be changed then you reset the inactive chains and configure them:

```
iptables -t nat -F chaingroup_b
iptables -t nat -F vps_1b
iptables -t nat -F vps_2b
iptables -t nat -F vps_3b

iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_b -j vps_1b
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_b -j vps_2b
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_b -j vps_3b
iptables -t nat -A chaingroup_b -j ACCEPT # stop applying rules

iptables -t nat -A vps_1a -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 4321 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:12345
```

After the preparation you make the inactive chain group the active one:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j chaingroup_b
```

Due to the `-j ACCEPT` at the end of `chaingroup_b` the still existing `chaingroup_a` is ignored. But you should delete it anyway in order to prevent `PREROUTING` from growing with each change:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 2
```

Comment: The reason why I delete all rules and then I insert them again is that newly created VPS could have the same ports but different local IP address.

Comment: @Welite Even if we assumethat this was the most feasible way (which I doubt) then you can prepare the inactive chains for all VPSs as slow as you like and then just exchange the VPS chains (20 commands in quick succession).

Comment: Can you give me some example please, I am not sure how you mean it.

Comment: @Welite I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact iptables can do it fast enough and I have tested that for nearly 1900 rules. All you need is to keep track of ip:ports in a list file, then write a script, e.g. a bash script like the followings, and reload ip:port's from that file

I assume each line in the file is something like realport:vps-ip:port

```
#/bin/bash
HOST=100.200.100.200 # your public address
LIST=/path/to/file

iptables -t nat -F
cat "$LIST" | while read line
do
realport=`echo $line|cut -f1 -d:`
vpsip=`echo $line|cut -f2 -d:`
port=`echo $line|cut -f3 -d:`
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $HOST --dport $realport -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination $vpsip:$port
done

iptables save
```

that way you only need to take care of the list.
You can also use other formats instead of realport:vps-ip:port, for example make it comma-separated. Then change -d: to -d, or whatever.

Comment: I have written myself an easy java program to do that for me, even when I am waiting for one command to execute before executing other still I find like 5% of the rules missing in the iptables.

Comment: Well, that's weird. Not sure, but java virtual machine may have something to do with that. I don't suggest java for system level tasks because of overhead and as you see unpredictability. If I was to go with a programming language for such tasks I would choose C. But shel scripts are the best with no weird errors so far.